# How to catch special indicated **characters** in an NSString and bold what's in between?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm having trouble bolding any characters between an indicated  pair of "**" characters. For example, in this NSString:

```
  "The Fox has ran **around** the corner."
```

should read: "The fox has ran **around** the corner"

here is my code :

```
NSString *questionString = queryString;
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:questionString];

NSRange range = [questionString rangeOfString:@"\\*([^**]+)\\*" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [mutableAttributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:AGHeavyFontName size:size]} range:range];
}

[[mutableAttributedString mutableString] replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, queryString.length)];

return mutableAttributedString;
```

I'm having issues- this code will still catch characters with one pair of "*"'s, so in this case,

```
   "The fox has ran *around the corner*
```

will still read as "The fox has ran **around** the corner", when it shouldnt.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use a regex for it. You've got it wrong. In particular, `[^**]` does not do what you think it does. Just use `rangeOfString:` (or `componentsSeparatedByString:` along with `componentsJoinedByString:`) to get a substring between two instances of the `**`.

Comment: @H2CO3 would love to see an example of what you are talking about

Comment: @User3294729579346597634 you can google and check what H2CO3 just told you. He gave you the exact method names. Its not that difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this may help you:

http://regex101.com/r/eF6pJ8

`\\*{2}([^*]*)\\*{2}`

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for me, I get an "Unknown Escape Sequence" warning

Comment: You might need to escape the backslashes then: `\\*{2}([^*]*)\\*{2}`